# NSDictionary writeToFile encoding only in UTF-8?

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, character-encoding, nsdictionary

By putting a `NSDictionary` to a file I get an UTF-8 encoded XML file. I need to write data to a file in `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`. Is `NSDictionary` UTF-8 only? How to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need a file encoded as ISO Latin-1? The problem with all encodings other than some form of Unicode is that they can't represent all possible characters.

The encoding is surely the least of your problems.  A dictionary's file representation is a property list file. It's unlikely that any code which requires Latin-1 encoding would understand that format. Indeed, the format is not guaranteed. It's not even guaranteed to be XML or textual. Property lists may be binary.

If you want to exchange data with a program that's going to use anything other than Cocoa's property list implementation, you should manually write the contents of the dictionary out in a format that's defined independently of Apple's property list format.

And, yes, if Cocoa does write the property list as XML, it's going to be UTF-8-encoded.

Comment: I believe it's not the best practice, but I need to write to a file a list of files with polish characters in their names (like: ą, ę, ś, ć, etc.) and only `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` lets me do this. When I use UTF-8 encoding I get wrong characters like _Ã³_ instead of _ó_.

Comment: I assure you that UTF-8 allows for the representation of those Polish characters. In fact, it's how StackOverflow and your browser represent them in this very page. The question is: what are you using to examine the file that is failing to correctly interpret those characters in UTF-8?

Comment: You were right. The problem occurs in the earlier stage: first I upload files to the server with `move_uploaded_file()` method, but as I `ZipArchive()` them on the server an archive is created with wrong characters in files names' - which didn't happen a few days before - could I change something by mistake or an administrator could change something in zip library? That's probably a question for another topic..